# php take raw input to a variable

Tags: java, php

Consider this piece of Java code
I need to do this in php

```
String SEPARATOR = "S39Er@T0R";
String input = "someS39Er@T0RDataS39Er@T0Rhere";
String[] val = input.split(SEPERATOR);
for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {

}
```

I need to store the data received from `file_get_contents('php://input')` which returns the raw post
and then from that string I need it to split and run a for loop
Can any one suggest how to implement the same code in php ?

Comment: It's called `separator`.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is. php has `explode()`, is that what you'Re looking for?

Comment: (I don'T really see the point of `input.split(input)` in Java either BTW... looks totally useless to me. what is that supposed to do? It shoudl do exactly the same as `String[] val = new String[] {input}`)

Comment: Oh, and last but not least: this has nothing to do with javascript. I'm editing that for you. Jeez, this post is wrong in so many ways...

Comment: @JohannesH. I am not aware on how to use explode or something like that that is why I had the question at first place, and ya I made a mistake with it was `input.split(SEPERATOR)` but I think based on a little logic you could read that input contained the `SEPARATOR` value so could have deduced that and of all php coding cant be done with java as far as i know so I added the tag of `Javascript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function splits a string by a string;
- [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) splits a string by a regex;
- [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct iterates over arrays [or objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php);

Combination of these is pretty straightforward:

```
$separator = 'S39Er@T0R';
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$splitPostData = explode($separator, $postData);
foreach($splitPostData as $postDataItem)
{
    // do something with $postDataItem
}
```

Comment: Also can you tell how to do .equals method for string comparison, and als get the size of $splitPostData

Comment: @user3262282: [string comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): `$str1 === $str2` (e.g. `if ($str1 === $str2) {...} else {...}`)

Comment: @user3262282: [size of array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php): `$sizeOfMyArray = count($myArray);`

Comment: @user3262282: [Byte-length of string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php): `$stringByteLength = strlen($myString);`. [Character-length of string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php): `$stringCharLength = mb_strlen($myString, 'UTF-8');`